# How do you remove a sub-string according to index from a Rust String or &str type?

Tags: rust

I have an &str type string from which I want to remove a sub-string. I have an algorithm to calculate the start and end positions of the part to be removed. How can I now remove the sub-string?

To illustrate this clearer, if I were using C++, I would do this:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>

    int main(){
        std::string foo = "Hello";
        int start = 2,stop = 4;
        std::cout<<foo;
        foo.erase(start, stop - start);
        std::cout<<std::endl<<foo<<std::endl;
    }
```

My code in Rust:

```
fn main(){
    let mut foo: &str = "hello";
    let start: i32 = 0;
    let stop: i32 = 4;
    //what goes here?
}
```

Comment: You may need to align the range inclusive part but this is the idea: `(&foo[..start]).to_string() + &foo[end..]`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`&str` is an immutable slice, it somewhat similar to [`std::string_view`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string_view), so you cannot modify it. Instead, you may use iterator and collect a new [`String`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/struct.String.html):

```rust
let removed: String = foo
    .chars()
    .take(start)
    .chain(foo.chars().skip(stop))
    .collect();
```

the other way would be an in-place `String` modifying:

```rust
let mut foo: String = "hello".to_string();

// ...

foo.replace_range((start..stop), "");
```

Keep in mind, however, that the last example semantically different, because it operates on byte indicies, rather than char ones. Therefore it may panic at wrong usage (e.g. when `start` offset lay at the middle of multi-byte char).

Comment: The `replace_range` way is likely faster. Also note that with `chars` the indexes are unlikely-to-be-useful codepoint indexes, while with `replace_range` they are byte-indexes, so the two examples are not completely equivalent.

Comment: Thanks, extended with a notice.

Comment: replace_range was exactly what I was looking for. Thanks so much! Could you clarify on this one more thing? As I understand, replace_range will only work for ASCII characters (those that have a fixed 1 byte size), and not with emojis in something like Unicode. Is this the only implication of using replace_range as opposed to chars?

Comment: `String` is an utf-8 string, which still can be used as a byte array, while preserving an invariant (valid utf-8 string). So you might get a panic quite easily: `"я".to_string().replace_range((1..), "")`, though this works: `"я".to_string().replace_range((0..), "")`. Therefore you can use `replace_range` if you know the proper `char` bounds.

Answer (score 0):

A solution that uses the character indexes of the beginning and the end of the substring to be removed with `splice()`:

```
fn remove(start: usize, stop: usize, s: &str) -> String {
    let mut v: Vec<char> = s.chars().collect();
    v.splice(start..stop, vec![]);
    v.iter().collect()
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=release&edition=2021&gist=54b1fc085d293bbc02b4b78175ae6eb1)

---

Kitsu's solution w/o lambda

```
fn remove(start: usize, stop: usize, s: &str) -> String {
    let mut rslt = "".to_string();
    for (i, c) in s.chars().enumerate() {
        if start > i || stop < i + 1 {
            rslt.push(c);
        }
    }
    rslt
}
```

…as fast as `replace_range` but can handle unicode character w/o character boundary calculations

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=release&edition=2021&gist=bf4b8b0f1d9ad886ac0702238177b11d)

Comment: I don't think it's as fast as `replace_range()` (did you benchmark?), and `replace_range()` can certainly handle Unicode.

Comment: @Friedman Apart from the fact that you first have to figure out the byte indices of these Unicode characters, then `replace_range()` *works* with Unicode.

Comment: Even then, I'm not sure this will be faster than finding the indices then using `replace_range()`.

Comment: @Friedman There is no `even then` but only `has to be always`. And since there is no `try_replace_range()`, your program will panic, if you made a mistake in finding the byte indices so that `replace_range()` *can work* with Unicode characters. This finding takes additional time, that must be taken into account.

Comment: Finding the byte indices is as simple as `let mut c = s.char_indices(); let start = c.nth(start).unwrap().0; let end = c.nth(end - start).unwrap().0;`. And I know this will take some time, but I still think this + `replace_range()` will be faster than your approach.

Comment: @Friedman As both solution needs a loop `replace_range()` has to be faster then `push()`.

Comment: And it is, because it does not involve growing and it uses a fast `memmove()`.

Answer (score 0):

If you prefer a *slightly* more performant way compared to `remove_range` that works on unicode you can use this:

```
fn remove_range(text: &str, start: usize, end: usize) -> String {
    let start = text.floor_char_boundary(start);
    let end = text.ceil_char_boundary(end);
    [&text[..start], &text[end..]].concat()
}
```

Just a note, since working with variable range characters can be troublesome, in this solution its uses an experimental feature `#![feature(round_char_boundary)]` to allow for "safe" string manipulation, the results might be different from expected if using complex multi-char arrangements, but it will not panic.

Comment: if not using unicode, just remove the xxx_char_boundary. it will work fine.

Comment: Why do you think it's more performant than `replace_range()`? I think the opposite.

Comment: i did not post any profiling because it "depends", but i would advise to profile for your specific architecture and instruction set, for me, yes it is slightly faster.

the worst case scenario is the same performance.